# Verification of the converse of Baire Category Theorem

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces, baire-category

One way to state the Baire Category Theorem is as follows: If $X \neq \emptyset$ is a complete metric space, then $X$ is nonmeager as a subset of itself.

Then it was mentioned that the converse, that there are nonmeager spaces which are not complete, of this theorem is false. I would like to ask if the following reasoning is correct:

**Proof:** Take $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and associate the usual metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ so that $((0,1),d)$ is a metric space. We claim this space is not complete. Take $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_{n=2}^\infty$. Then $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, however $0 \notin (0,1)$. Thus, not complete. However, $$(0,1) = \bigcup_{n \geq 1}\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ is nonmeager since $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right) \subset (0,1)$ clearly is not rare.

Edit: [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That counterexample is correct, but the argument is not. You claim that$$(0,1)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(0,\frac1n\right),\tag1$$So what? Asserting that $(0,1)$ is a counterexample means that $(0,1)$ cannot be written as a countable union of rare subsets of itself, and the equality $(1)$ doesn't allow you to deduce that.

The space $(0,1)$ cannot be written as a countable union of rare subsets of itself because it is locally compact, and Baire's theorem holds if “complete metric space” gets replaced by “locally compact topological space”.

Comment: But aren't all $\{q_n\}$ rare in $\mathbb{Q}$? Then $\mathbb{Q}$ would be meager?

Comment: What does “rare” mean in this context? I teach Topology, but I've never saw it in a Topology textbook. And that word does not appear [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space).

Comment: Rare is a synonym for [nowhere dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_dense_set).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I've edited the question with some definitions used in the book.

Comment: I had misunderstood your question. What do you think now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos So, my proof is half completed because I must consider every ways of writing $(0,1)$ as an union of sets. In this situation, $(0,1)$ is nonmeager, that is, for any way we write $(0,1) = \bigcup A_i$ of some countable family of sets $\{A_i\}$, there will be an order $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $A_k$ is non rare. Hence, this happens because $(0,1)$ is locally compact? I am trying to understand why being locally compact guarantee us that there's such set $A_k$ that's not rare in the union.

Comment: Because in a locally compact space (just as in the case of complete metric spaces) a countable union of rare sets is never the whole space.